# How to return a value from a range of values

Tags: excel-formula

I would appreciate it if someone can answer this.

Lets say I got multiple rows with three column with min, max and the return value . And I wanted to create a single formula to search the min and max value and then gave back a return value based on the row . Let me just show it :

```
Min     Max     Return
0.01    10      0
10.01   20      5
20.01   30      12
30.01   40      15
```

Input   7 <---- User input
Return  0 <---- This should be calculated based on the user input against the table

Input   33 <---- User input
Return  15 <---- This should be calculated based on the user input against the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'll attempt another try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C2:C5*(F1>=A2:A5)*(F1<=B2:B5))
```

C2:C5 are the results, A2:A5 the minmum values, B2:B5 the maximum values and F1 the actual value.

Basically, SUMPRODUCT can be used as it does the calculation for every row and sums up the results. If the test succeeds, 1 is returned, otherwise 0. Thus, only the successful test will have a 1, all others will multiply their result with 0.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much. It work. Was really scratching my head with this earlier.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean a SQL Query, here is the query  that jsut do the job for you :

```
 SELECT Return from TABLE_Name
      WHERE
            Input >= Min AND Input < Max
```

Comment: Nope. I mean excel formula. If any that is.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, some nested `IF`s would do like (assuming input in A4 and the ranges like in the table):

```
=IF(AND(A4>B1,A4<B2),B3,IF(AND(A4>C1,A4<C2),C3,...
```

For more complex (meaning longer) tables you could also use a "helper" column (Column D):

```
IF(AND($A$4>B1,$A$4<B2),B3,"")
```

"drag" this down to copy it and then sum the column to get the result.

All a bit of a mess, but I can't think of any more elegant solution using excel formulas.

Comment: so there is no shorter formula. Just thought it would be great and awesome if a single line formula can do that.

thank you.

Comment: In fact, there is one - see my other answer ;-)